# Django-tinymce not working; Getting a normal textarea instead

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-admin, tinymce

I'm trying to use `django-tinymce` to make fields that are editable through Django's admin with a TinyMCE field. I am using `tinymce.models.HTMLField` as the field for this.

The problem is it's not working. I get a normal textarea. I check the HTML source, and it seems like all the code needed for TinyMCE is there. I also confirmed that the statically-served JavaScript file is indeed being served. But for some reason it isn't working.

What I did notice though, is that if I avoid setting `TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True` in the settings file, it does start to work. What can cause this behavior?

Comment: I also have this problem, will be greatful to see the answer :) Using django 1.1.1 and django_tinymce 1.5

Comment: I see this is an issue on the django-tinymce site: http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/issues/detail?id=34

Answer (score 0):

What are your webserver and web browser.  Perhaps it is trying to set the gzip/bzip header and the server isn't processing it... so it goes out plaintext but the client expects compressed?

Comment: Server is Django's `runserver`. The browser is Chrome. (Though I know Chrome renders TinyMCE fine in other cases.)